# Unable to get value in view after form post in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my ControllerClass

```
public class ScheduleClassController extends SimpleFormController {

public ScheduleClassController() {
    setCommandClass(ScheduleClass.class);
    setCommandName("scheduleClass");
}

protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command) throws Exception {

    ScheduleClass wiziqClass = (ScheduleClass) command;
    System.out.println(wiziqClass);
    return new ModelAndView("classdetail", "ScheduleClass", wiziqClass);

}
}
```

This is my springapp-servelet.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <!-- <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> -->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean name="/index.htm" class="org.sakaiproject.wiziq.tool.HelloWorldController">
    <property name="sakaiProxy" ref="org.sakaiproject.wiziq.logic.SakaiProxy" />
</bean>

<bean name="/schedule.htm" class="org.sakaiproject.wiziq.tool.ScheduleClassController">
    <property name="formView" value="schedule" />
    <property name="successView" value="classdetail" />
</bean>
```

This is my classdetail.jsp

```
<jsp:directive.include file="/templates/includes.jsp" />
<jsp:directive.include file="/templates/header.jsp" />

hello there
${wiziqClass.name}

<jsp:directive.include file="/templates/footer.jsp" />
```

After submitting the form i land on this view but not getting the wiziqClass.name here 
I have made Model and added getter and setter there.

What i'm doing wrong? Not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code the name of the attribute is 'ScheduleClass' and not 'wiziqClass'... So change the expression in your jsp

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object command) throws Exception {

  ScheduleClass wiziqClass = (ScheduleClass) command;
  System.out.println(wiziqClass);
  return new ModelAndView("classdetail", "ScheduleClass", wiziqClass);
}
```

${ScheduleClass.name}

Answer (score 1):

Please change any one of place . Don't change in two places.

```
 protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, Object command) throws Exception {

      ScheduleClass wiziqClass = (ScheduleClass) command;
      System.out.println(wiziqClass);
      return new ModelAndView("classdetail", "wiziqClass", wiziqClass);
}
```

**or**

```
 ${ScheduleClass.name}
```

Comment: this is my form `<form:form method="POST" commandName="scheduleClass">` and when i add `return new ModelAndView("index");` its still going to classDetail pages ?? i tried you option also still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Got it working the main problem is that the `onSubmit` was not working i mistakenly removed
BindException errors from
  `onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command,BindException errors)`
 and that was causing the error second error was what M.Dienum told

Thanks to both of you